# DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, layoutId) is null

Tags: android, android-databinding

```
binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, layoutId);
```

But the binding is null.

This sometimes has a value, other times null.

The activity:

```
public class WellcomeActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        WellcomeBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.wellcome);
        vvv = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.main_vf);
    }
}
```

`vvv` can be found; `WellcomeBinding` can be found; `binding` is null.

My English is not very good.

请多担待 Please pay more attention

- XML file no error
- It is an old project
- Compile no error
- it has a RuntimeException only.

The xml like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout>

    <!--<data>-->

        <!--<variable-->
            <!--name="vm"-->
            <!--type="com.aaron.lazy.base.activity.BaseViewModel"></variable>-->
    <!--</data>-->

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/launcher_default">

        <ViewFlipper
            android:id="@+id/main_vf"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="向右滑动3次以上"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="30dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</layout>
```

Comment: Add logs, there is a chance you have an error in your xml file. Is this a new project? if it is, please include the use of androidx packages.

Comment: android studio 3.3.2

Comment: xml file no error
it is a old project 
compile no error

Comment: what is the name of your xml file ?

Comment: the name is wellcome.xml

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using:

```java
WellcomeBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(getLayoutInflater(), R.layout.wellcome, null, false);
setContentView(binding.getRoot());
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how you do it:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    val binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Double check that you have databinding enabled in your `build.gradle`

```
android {
    buildFeatures {
        dataBinding true
    }
}
```

Especially in libraries this is easily forgotten. Remember that all modules that depend on a library using databinding needs to enable it (even if that module doesn't use databinding itself)!

Comment: I don't think this will be the issue. Cuz the DataBinding file will only be generated only if its enabled. Even the context action to convert layout to data binding will not be displayed.