# How to fixed myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-context

i'm a beginner in android kotlin, when i run my first app this error occurred

> Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?

I know the solution is to add this code

```
myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
```

But, I just don't understand why `myIntent` is turning red and it says

> unresloved reference: myIntent

This is my code where the error comes from

```
holder.setClick(object:IRecyclerClick{
        override fun onClick(view: View, posistion: Int) {
            myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
            context.startActivity(Intent (context,ChapterActivity::class.java))
            com.tutorial.kotlinfirebasecomicreader.Common.Common.selected_comic=comicList[position]
        }

    })
```

I know this is just my inability to solve this problem, I have tried many ways but still not successful,
that's why I come to stackoverflow. Is there anyone can help me?

MyComicAdepter.kt

```
package com.tutorial.kotlinfirebasecomicreader.Adapter

import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.graphics.Insets.add
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.core.view.OneShotPreDrawListener.add
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso
import com.tutorial.kotlinfirebasecomicreader.ChapterActivity
import com.tutorial.kotlinfirebasecomicreader.Interface.IRecyclerClick
import com.tutorial.kotlinfirebasecomicreader.Model.Chapter
import com.tutorial.kotlinfirebasecomicreader.Model.Comic
import com.tutorial.kotlinfirebasecomicreader.R

class MyComicAdapter(internal var context:Context, internal var comicList: 
List<Comic>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<MyComicAdapter.MyViewHolder> () {

class MyViewHolder(itemView:View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView), 
View.OnClickListener {
    var imageView:ImageView
    var texView:TextView
    lateinit var iRecyclerClick: IRecyclerClick

    fun setClick(iRecyclerClick: IRecyclerClick)
    {
        this.iRecyclerClick = iRecyclerClick
    }

    init {
        imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.comic_image) as ImageView
        texView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.comic_name) as TextView

        itemView.setOnClickListener(this)
    }

    override fun onClick(v: View?) {

        iRecyclerClick.onClick(v!!,adapterPosition)

    }

}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): 
MyViewHolder {
    val itemView = 
LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.comic_item,parent,false)
    return  MyViewHolder(itemView)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
    Picasso.get().load(comicList[position].Image).into(holder.imageView)
    holder.texView.text = comicList[position].Name

    holder.setClick(object:IRecyclerClick{
        override fun onClick(view: View, posistion: Int) {
            val myIntent= Intent (context,ChapterActivity::class.java)
            myIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
           context.startActivity(Intent(context,ChapterActivity::class.java))
          com.tutorial.kotlinfirebasecomicreader.Common.Common.
          selected_comic=comicList[position]
        }

    })
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return comicList.size
}
}
```

My Logcat

```
2021-03-03 09:10:32.452 4804-4804/com.tutorial.kotlinfirebasecomicreader E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.tutorial.kotlinfirebasecomicreader, PID: 4804
android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?
    at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:1003)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:979)
    at android.content.ContextWrapper.startActivity(ContextWrapper.java:402)
    at com.tutorial.kotlinfirebasecomicreader.Adapter.MyComicAdapter$onBindViewHolder$1.onClick(MyComicAdapter.kt:61)
    at com.tutorial.kotlinfirebasecomicreader.Adapter.MyComicAdapter$MyViewHolder.onClick(MyComicAdapter.kt:41)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7281)
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7258)
    at android.view.View.access$3700(View.java:804)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27995)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:907)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Lo
```

Line 61

```
com.tutorial.kotlinfirebasecomicreader.Common.Common.selected_comic=comicList[position]
```

Line 41

```
iRecyclerClick.onClick(v!!,adapterPosition)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to initialize myIntent first, then set your flags, and finally start your intent:

Edit: Yout setClick() should look like this:

```
holder.setClick(object:IRecyclerClick{
        override fun onClick(view: View, posistion: Int) {
             com.tutorial.kotlinfirebasecomicreader.Common.Common.
             selected_comic=comicList[position]                 
             val myIntent= Intent (context,ChapterActivity::class.java)
             myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
             context.startActivity(myIntent)
             
        }

    })
```

I don't know what this line does, but i'd put it before `startActivity(intent)`

```
com.tutorial.kotlinfirebasecomicreader.Common.Common.selected_comic=comicList[position]
```

You cand find more info here: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity#kotlin

Comment: I have already initialized what you said but it still showing the same error
The error comes from this line `context.startActivity(Intent (context,ChapterActivity::class.java))`

Comment: Can you post the whole exepction on your main post

Comment: myIntent is finally fixed now but i think `(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)` does not recognize my app

Comment: Try: myIntent .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

Comment: It still showing the same errors. The errors refers to lines 41 and 61 which I have added recently above

Comment: Check setClick() , you are not using myIntent correctly, i've edited my answer

Comment: I have followed exactly the code that you told me, but if I change this code `context.startActivity(Intent(context, ChapterActivity::class.java))` into this `startActivity(myIntent)` this error occur `Type mismatch.
Required:
Context
Found:
Intent`

Comment: it told me to create function `startActivity`

Comment: Use: context.startActivity(myIntent) , because when you are using context.startActivity(Intent(context, ChapterActivity::class.java))  as you see you are not passing myIntent.

Comment: Seems like it fixed the error but then another one have just occur `Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.tutorial.kotlinfirebasecomicreader/com.tutorial.kotlinfirebasecomicreader.ChapterActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: DataBindingUtil.setConte….layout.activity_chapter) must not be null`

Comment: Well that's another subject, maybe post another question or see if this helps: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56082570/databindingutil-setcontentviewthis-layoutid-is-null)

Comment: Thanks for your response this far.
Glad to meet you :)

Comment: Don't forget to check the answer as accepted to help others too.

Comment: Sure why not? Great answer